# how to get webpacker to load css if extract_css is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have the following pack file:

```
// app/javascript/packs/styles.js 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
```

Unless I set `extract_css: true` in config/webpack.yml I do not see how to get these styles to load.

If I set `extract_css: true` and include `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'styles' %>` in the layout everything seems to work.

But then what is the point of `extract_css: false`  why would you ever NOT want this?   Because its the default webpacker configuration I feel as if I am missing something important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `extract_css: false`, the styles are provided by the webpack js runtime as blob urls and injected into the document `<head>` inline (assuming you have a corresponding `javascript_pack_tag`).

One use case for this approach in development is to better support hot module reloading for CSS.

Comment: thank you the clue here was that you have to have the corresponding `javascript_pack_tag`.   so If I understand you have both a `javascript_pack_tag` AND a `stylesheet_pack_tag`, BUT the stylesheet_pack_tag is ignored by the system in development.

Comment: Yep and you can verify the `stylesheet_pack_tag` behavior here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/d905149d8a33303a9c24002721bc872ef95a8b6f/lib/webpacker/helper.rb#L129

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you extract the css, webpack will generate that standalone css file so you can link it. If you don't extract it, the CSS is bundled insde the js file and webpack will process it when the page loads and inserts the CSS in a `style` tag in the `head` tag of the document.

To extract the CSS from the js file it uses the mini-css-extract plugin.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css

In some cases you may want to keep the css on the bundle if you want to have all the js and css with only one request.